# Merge list items with similar content in r?

Tags: r, list, merge

I have list v:

`v <- list(c("12", "1"), c("12", "2"), c("12", "3"), c("13", "1"), c("22", "3"), c("30", "4"))`

and I need to merge the lines of this list which share the same first number by joining the second numbers separated by a comma, such that the resulting list w is like this:

`w <- list(c("12", "1,2,3"), c("13", "1"), c("22", "3"), c("30", "4"))`

```
> vv <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, v)
> names(vv) <- c("v1", "v2")
> vv
  v1 v2
1 12  1
2 12  2
3 12  3
4 13  1
5 22  3
6 30  4
> vvv <-vv %>%
+   group_by(v1) %>%
+   summarise(v3 = paste0(v2, collapse = ",")) 
> vvv
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  v1    v3   
  <fct> <chr>
1 12    1,2,3
2 13    1    
3 22    3    
4 30    4    
> w <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(vvv)))
> w
$V1
   v1    v3 
   12 1,2,3 
Levels: 1,2,3 12

$V2
v1 v3 
13  1 
Levels: 1 13

$V3
v1 v3 
22  3 
Levels: 22 3

$V4
v1 v3 
30  4 
Levels: 30 4

> w <- lapply(as.list(1:dim(vvv)[1]), function(x) as.character(vvv[x[1],]))
> w
[[1]]
[1] "1"     "1,2,3"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "3" "3"

[[4]]
[1] "4" "4"

> w <- base::lapply(as.list(1:dim(vvv)[1]), function(x) as.character(vvv[x[1],]))
> w
[[1]]
[1] "1"     "1,2,3"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "3" "3"

[[4]]
[1] "4" "4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R option using apply family of functions

```
#get 1st value from each list
group_values <- sapply(v, `[[`, 1)

#For each unique group value combine all the other values in one 
#comma separated string
Map(c, unique(group_values), 
    tapply(v, group_values, function(x) 
    toString(unlist(sapply(x, tail, -1)))))

#$`12`
#[1] "12"      "1, 2, 3"

#$`13`
#[1] "13" "1" 

#$`22`
#[1] "22" "3" 

#$`30`
#[1] "30" "4"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

vv <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, v)
names(vv) <- c("v1", "v2")
vvv <-vv %>%
  group_by(v1) %>%
  summarise(v3 = paste0(v2, collapse = ",")) 
w <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(vvv)))
w



$V1
[1] "12"    "1,2,3"

$V2
[1] "13" "1" 

$V3
[1] "22" "3" 

$V4
[1] "30" "4" 



w <- lapply(as.list(1:dim(vvv)[1]), function(x) as.character(vvv[x[1],]))
w

[[1]]
[1] "12"    "1,2,3"

[[2]]
[1] "13" "1" 

[[3]]
[1] "22" "3" 

[[4]]
[1] "30" "4"
```

## Try this

```
v <- list(c("12", "1"), c("12", "2"), c("12", "3"), c("13", "1"), c("22", "3"), c("30", "4"))
vv <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, v)
names(vv) <- c("v1", "v2")
vv

  v1 v2
1 12  1
2 12  2
3 12  3
4 13  1
5 22  3
6 30  4

vvv <-vv %>%
  dplyr::group_by(v1) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(v3 = paste0(v2, collapse = ",")) 
vvv

  v1    v3   
  <chr> <chr>
1 12    1,2,3
2 13    1    
3 22    3    
4 30    4 

w <- lapply(as.list(1:dim(vvv)[1]), function(x) as.character(vvv[x[1],]))
w

[[1]]
[1] "12"    "1,2,3"

[[2]]
[1] "13" "1" 

[[3]]
[1] "22" "3" 

[[4]]
[1] "30" "4"
```

## Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
lapply(seq_len(nrow(vvv)),
       function(i) as.character(setDF(lapply(vvv, "[", i))))
```

## This may solve

```
v <- list(c("12", "1"), c("12", "2"), c("12", "3"), c("13", "1"), c("22", "3"), c("30", "4"))
vv <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, v)
names(vv) <- c("v1", "v2")
vvv <-vv %>%
  dplyr::group_by(v1) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(v3 = paste0(v2, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate(v1 = as.character(v1))
w <- lapply(as.list(1:dim(vvv)[1]), function(x) as.character(vvv[x[1],]))
w
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to keep it in list form, rather than a data frame? (not in V1, V2, etc)?

Comment: @esti That was list too, but I add the code that will make `w` as you wrote in your question. Please check it out.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! I just tried that new line, but I get this list:
[[1]]
[1] "1"     "1,2,3"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "1"

[[3]]
[1] "3" "3"

[[4]]
[1] "4" "4"

Comment: @esti Did you get `vvv` properly? Is the problem is `3` in `[[3]]` and `4` in `[[4]]`? Would you try **Try this** what I add above and check if it gives something weird.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result, the problem is all the first numbers, they are 1, 2, 3, and 4 when they should be 12, 13, 22, and 30

Comment: @esti I add the result for each input in **try this** part. I recommend you to give me the same format results at your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239061/discussion-between-esti-and-park).